# Umbraco & Razor. Filter selection by dropdown value

Tags: razor, filter, umbraco

I have a selection generated from the children of the current page. Within that selection (let's call it Fruit) I have items and each item has a fruitType.

This code doesn't work:

```
@{
    var selection = CurrentPage.Children("fruit").Where("Visible");
}
<ul>
    @foreach(var item in selection){
        @if(@item.fruitType == "Apple"){
        <li>
            <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a><br/>
            @item.fruitName<br>
            @item.fruitType<br>
            @if (item.image != null && !(item.image is Umbraco.Core.Dynamics.DynamicNull))
                        { var m = Umbraco.Media(item.image);
                            <img src="@m.Url" alt="Picture of @item.Name" />
                        }
        </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is to only list the items with a fruitType of "Apple". This value is selected from a "fruitType" dropdown list and I've tried using both the numeric and string values that Umbraco uses from Dropdown datatypes.

It all works perfectly if I remove the if conditional except that it displays all fruit types.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to use the typed version (Model.Content)  instead of CurrentPage  for a better intellisense. Also try printing @item.GetPropertyValue<string>("fruitType") inside the loop to see the actual value stored in the property fruitType. PS: in the line  @if(@item.fruitType == "Apple"){  you have one extra @ before item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*sigh* Just one too many declarations..

Turns out neither the **if** nor the **item** references need the additional @ declaration in front of it so the correct code looks like:

```
@{
    var selection = CurrentPage.Children("fruit").Where("Visible");
}
<ul>
    @foreach(var item in selection){
        if(item.fruitType == "Apple"){
        <li>
            <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a><br/>
            @item.fruitName<br>
            @item.fruitType<br>
            @if (item.image != null && !(item.image is Umbraco.Core.Dynamics.DynamicNull))
                        { var m = Umbraco.Media(item.image);
                            <img src="@m.Url" alt="Picture of @item.Name" />
                        }
        </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```